# Encoding option CODEPAGE not working for OPENROWSET in MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server, json, postgresql, encoding, openrowset

I am trying to migrate data from Postgres database to SQL server. For this, I am exporting the Postgres data into JSON format, and the idea is to insert the data into my tables (I already have the schema from Postgres database imported into SQL server).

I am playing around with the OPENROWSET function, but there seem to be problems with the encoding. I noticed in the documentation that there is a CODEPAGE option that should solve this problem, but it doesn't do anything in the way I am specifying it.

This is my example query:

```
 SELECT users.*
 FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'path_to_some.json', SINGLE_CLOB, CODEPAGE = '65001') as j
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
 WITH(id int, 
 first_name nvarchar(max),
 last_name nvarchar(max), 
 email nvarchar(max), 
 accepts_marketing bit, 
 created_at datetime, 
 updated_at datetime) AS users
 order by id
```

Does anyone have an idea what am I missing here?

Comment: Why don't you use an Postgres driver to talk from one database to the other?  Why involve Json at all? It doesn't offer any benefit over CSV anyway. BTW `CODEPAGE` is for ASCII text. 65001 is Unicode, UTF8 specifically

Comment: You could use SSIS or the `Import Data` wizard to load data from Postgres directly into SQL Server. It's faster than setting up a linked server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I actually explored that option, but it seems too complicated to me. I want to create a one-time export from Postgres to MSSQL. I need something simple here, as the task seems as something that should be straightforward.

Comment: The Import Data wizard is also something that I have tried. It is a very nice tool, very simple, but the problem with it is the column delimiter. I have a relatively large amount of data to migrate. In the data, there are all kinds of special symbols. 
I have tried every special symbol I could think of and there are always some text records that contain this symbol and the import operation could not perform a clean import. 
From what I saw it is not possible to specify more complex delimiter than one character.

Comment: What column delimiter? You don't need any delimiter if you read data from Postgres and transfer it to SQL Server. A for "very simple", on the contrary, it's an entire ETL framework. The wizard generates only a direct mapping using that framework. If you have a lot of data, direct transfer with SSIS will be a LOT faster that first exporting to JSON, then importing the text file

Comment: Ok, Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos. I installed the postgre native driver and got the provider in the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard :) 

The delimiter was from Flat File Source. I was using that until now. Unfortunately, there are still problems. I opened a [**new question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975322/sql-server-import-and-export-wizard-and-postgresql) about this.

Answer (score 1):

I think CODEPAGE (bulk_option) is not working with SINGLE_CLOB, but only with FORMATFILE option.
From OPENROWSET spec:

> { FORMATFILE = 'format_file_path' [ <bulk_options> ]
>          | SINGLE_BLOB | SINGLE_CLOB | SINGLE_NCLOB }

Should read:

> { (FORMATFILE = 'format_file_path' optionally <bulk_options>)
>          or SINGLE_BLOB or SINGLE_CLOB or SINGLE_NCLOB }