# SQL Server Import and Export Wizard and PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssms

I am trying to export data from PostgreSQL to MSSQL Server.

Currently, I am exploring the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

I have installed the *native postgres driver* and got the **.Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL**. Everything seemed fine until I tried to use it.

I got the following: Cannot get the supported data types from the database connection

[image: postgre native driver problems]

Is this a driver problem or am I missing something?

**Update:**

Like **@Panagiotis Kanavos** suggested I have installed [OLEDB driver](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/oledb/)

There seems to be a problem with it.

I fill the required data, Test the connection, it says that it is successfully established, but when I click Next to continue with the Wizard I get:

===================================

Cannot get string literals from the database connection "Provider=PostgreSQL OLE DB Provider;User ID=postgres;Data Source=localhost;Location=MyDb;Extended Properties=". (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

===================================

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (DTSWizard)

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

After clicking Next:

[image]

There isn't any useful information about this problem. If anyone has any idea?

Comment: Maybe. The native driver is *not* the `.NET Data Provider`. Have you tried the OLEDB driver ? Which driver did you install? It would be (a lot) easier to find an answer if you posted the *errors*, not a screenshot of the errors. You can't google screenshots

Comment: I actually have posted the error. At least the error message. :) 

About the OLEDB driver, I have installed it. At least I think so. [Is this it](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/oledb/)? See my edit for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful using the ODBC drivers (64 bit). 32bit drivers had some memory issues on large tables.  See this post:
[Migrating from PostgreSQL to SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711028/migrating-from-postgres-to-sql-server-2008)